# How do I break out of a python while loop in this case?

Tags: python

I don't know how to break out of a python while loop when turtle arrived on `t.ycor == 0`

```
import turtle
import msvcrt

turtle.setup(700, 300, 0, 0)
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.up()
t.goto(-300,0)
t.down()
t.write("Start\n(" + str(t.xcor()) + ", " + str(t.ycor()) + ")", False, "center", ("",15))
while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            c = msvcrt.getch().decode(encoding = 'UTF-8')
        if c == 'j':
            t.left(3)
        elif c == 'k':
            t.right(3)
        elif c == 'g':
            t.forward(5)
            t.right(3)
        while t.ycor() > 0:
            t.forward(10)
            t.right(3)
t.write("End\n(" + str(t.xcor()) + ", " + str(t.ycor()) + ")", False, "center", ("",15))
print("When angle is", str(t.heading()), ", difference of x position is ", str(t.xcor()+300))
input("Press ENTER key to end")
```

I want to break out of `while True:` after `while t.ycor() > 0:` is done,
but I don't know how....

Comment: use `break` keyword after if statement check

Comment: `break` <- Breaks a while loop

Comment: break out 'while True:' using 'break' after 'while t.ycor() > 0:' is done. Should i fix 'while True:'?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are searching for this:

```
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        c = msvcrt.getch().decode(encoding = 'UTF-8')
    if c == 'j':
        t.left(3)
    elif c == 'k':
        t.right(3)
    elif c == 'g':
        t.forward(5)
        t.right(3)
    while t.ycor() > 0:
        t.forward(10)
        t.right(3)
    break
```

If so, a better solution would be to eleminate the "while True:", because of the break the while loop is only used once - so the while is unnecessary.